# Excel VBA to Concatenate cells in a column but only up to last row -1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to get a column from a table, add concatenation to it, so I can run it directly via the SQL Power query to fetch data from SQL.

So far, I have the main table from which I can fetch the rows. Then I do a concatenation of 'CELLVALUE',..... following which I can then run it via the parameters.

Problem is that when using the concatenation, even the last cell value ends up with this format of 'FRISTCELLVALUE',......,'LASTCELLVALUE',

As you know for SQL, the last value should be 'LASTCELLVALUE' in order to use the SQL IN statement.

I tried to manually input the formula into my new table. It looks like this.

```
=CONCATENATE("'";tablename[@col];"'";",")
```

But even the last row ends up with the **,** which I want to avoid.
Any way how I can have the last cell value to NOT HAVE the , ? Maybe either via a formula or VBA?

Thanks.

Comment: Im a little confused but are you looking for `TEXTJOIN`?

Comment: No. Lets say, col in tablename has Apple, Banana. Using CONCATENATE, I want to get it to 'Apple','Banana' Right now it displays as 'Apple','Banana,

Comment: So you are looking for `TEXTJOIN`....read about it =)

Comment: How many column do you have? Does every cells has data or there may empty/null cells?

Comment: Thanks for the Textjoin func. But when I try this =TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;worksheet1!F:F) it also includes the header.
@Harun24HR Its just one column that I want to join. Yes, there no empty or null values

Comment: @LifeOfPy Try answer below and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `TEXTJOIN()` like-

```
="'" & TEXTJOIN("','",TRUE,A1:A30) & "'"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I managed to get the data this way, =TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;sheet1!F:F). Textjoin works nicely here. Only problem is, it also takes the header value. Anyway I could avoid this?

Comment: If it is in table then refer table column which will avoid header.